# create lagged variables for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame consisting of sales data of a store:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create a list of hourly timestamps from May 14, 2023, 00:00 to May 17, 2023, 23:00
timestamps = pd.date_range(start='2023-05-14', end='2023-05-17 23:00', freq='H')

# Create a DataFrame with the timestamps as the index
df = pd.DataFrame(index=timestamps)

# Generate random sales data for each hourly timestamp
df['sales'] = np.random.randint(low=100, high=1000, size=len(timestamps))

df = df.reset_index()

df.columns = ['t', 'sales']
```

So basically

```
                     sales
2023-05-14 00:00:00
2023-05-14 01:00:00
2023-05-14 02:00:00
```

Given an hour h and i in  `[i for i in range(48)]`, I need to create a new column called sales_i which is the sales of the store from (48 + i) hours ago if (48 + i) <= (72 + h), otherwise from 48 - (48 + i) % (71 + h) hours ago. For example:

```
                     sales_0               sales_1              ... sales_35            sales 36
2023-05-17 11:00:00  2023-05-15 11:00:00   2023-05-15 10:00:00      2023-05-14 00:00:00 2023-05-15 12:00:00
```

The above example indicates that sales_0 should correspond to the sales data at 2023-05-15 11:00:00. Basically we have a 48-hour window around 2023-05-15 11:00:00. Usually this kind of result can be achieved by using shift. However due to the way this is set up, we need to shift different amounts for different hours, so this cannot be possibly done by shifting, unless we deal with each hour separately.

I can do the following:

```
def convert(row, i):
    h = row['t'].hour
    if row['t'].hour + 72 >=  48 + i and df.loc[df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 + i), 'sales'].size > 0:
        return df.loc[df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 + i), 'sales'].values.item()
    elif row['t'].hour + 72 <  48 + i and df.loc[df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 - (48 + i) % (71 + h)), 'sales'].values.size > 0:
        return df.loc[df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 - (48 + i) % (71 + h)), 'sales'].values.item()
    else:
        return None

list = [i for i in range(48)]
for i in list:
    df['sales' + str(i)] = df.apply(lambda row: convert(row, i), axis=1)
```

but this is not very efficient and slow.

Also suppose I have an extra dimension called store, then to do this for each store I can do:

```
def convert(row, i):
    h = row['t'].hour
    if row['t'].hour + 72 >=  48 + i and df.loc[(df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 + i)) & (df.store == row.store), 'sales'].size > 0:
        return df.loc[(df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 + i)) & (df.store == row.store), 'sales'].values.item()
    elif row['t'].hour + 72 <  48 + i and df.loc[(df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 - (48 + i) % (71 + h))) & (df.store == row.store), 'sales'].values.size > 0:
        return df.loc[(df.t == row['t'] - 
    pd.DateOffset(hours=48 - (48 + i) % (71 + h))) & (df.store == row.store), 'sales'].values.item()
    else:
        return None
```

which is again super slow.

Comment: what is `row['t']`?

Comment: was just reseting the index column to be named as t, thanks for pointing it out. Have revised accordingly.

Comment: your code is not running for me, did you check that it's valid? Which python/pandas versions did you use?

Comment: my apology, cleaned the code a bit. It should run now.